# I want to change value of count in item by clicking on the button if the product is exist plus one on count and this appear for user

Tags: javascript

```
let allBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".add-btn");
let productsName = document.querySelectorAll(".product-sale");
let alertBtn = document.querySelector(".btn-alert");
let closeAlert = document.querySelector(".close-alert");
let cartNum = document.querySelector(".cart-num");
let alertContinue = document.querySelector(".continue-alert");
let body = document.querySelector(".body");
let overLayer = document.querySelector(".dark-layer");
let checkNum = document.querySelector('.check-num');
let navCart = document.querySelector(".cart-navbar");
let productsCart = document.querySelector(".cart-products");
let img1 = document.querySelectorAll(".img-1");
let price = document.querySelectorAll(".price");
let myCart = document.querySelector(".nav-cart");
let closeNavCart = document.querySelector(".close-nav-cart");
let navNum = document.querySelector(".nav-num");
let count = document.querySelector(".count")

function disableScrolling() {
    var x = window.scrollX;
    var y = window.scrollY;
    window.onscroll = function() {
        window.scrollTo(x, y);
    };
}

function enableScrolling() {
    window.onscroll = function() {};
}

let cartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems")) || [];

cartNum.textContent = cartItems.length;

navNum.textContent = cartItems.length;

function addItemToCart(itemName, itemImg, itemPrice) {
    const existingItem = cartItems.find(item => item.name === itemName);

    if (existingItem) {
        cartItems.count += 1;
    } else {
        let cartItem = {
            name: itemName,
            image: itemImg,
            price: itemPrice,
            count: 1
        };

        cartItems.push(cartItem);
    }

    localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItems));

    cartNum.textContent = cartItems.length;

    navNum.textContent = cartItems.length;
}

function loadCartItems() {
    for (let i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++) {
        let node = document.createElement(div);
        let text = document.createElement("div");
        let name = document.createElement("a");
        let pricea = document.createElement("p");
        let imgs = document.createElement("img");
        let item = cartItems[i].name;
        let prices = cartItems[i].price.split(" ")[0];
        node.classList.add("item");
        imgs.classList.add("src");
        imgs.src = cartItems[i].image;
        name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
        pricea.appendChild(document.createTextNode(1 X $ {
            prices
        }));
        text.append(name, pricea);
        node.append(imgs, text);
        productsCart.appendChild(node);

        disableScrolling();

    }
}

pricea.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`1 X ${prices}`));
```

I tried make pricea like this `` pricea.appendChild (document.createTextNode (`${count} X ${prices}`) ``; but the value doesn't changed in HTML and make count in div special and call this div by JavaScript and change his value but it doesn't work too

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable. And remove the code that isn't related to the problem, like `disableScrolling()`.

Comment: Your code is missing the backticks around the argument to `createTextNode()`.

Comment: You really don't need to use `createTextNode()`. Just set whatever value you have as the `.textContent` of the appropriate element as `.textContent` sets the text of an implicit text node.